# Partitions of fixed length where certain numbers are disallowed

Tags: integer-partitions, trees

I want to know if an elementary Way of counting irreducible trees of order n could be

The number of partitions of 2n-2 of length n with 2 disallowed as a summand? I have only a phone right now, no computer ...

Comment: I don't know what "irreducible" means, in the context of trees.

Comment: Thank you. It's the problem from the Good Will Hunting movie: Find all non-isomorphic homeomorphically irreducible trees of order 10. Just found out it's not that easy, because there are non-isomorphic trees with the same sequence of node orders.

Comment: OK. The sequence is tabulated, with references, at http://oeis.org/A000014

Comment: Previous discussion on this site: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386804/finding-number-of-homeomorphically-irreducible-trees-of-degree-n